# Redimensionar imagem com CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou com uma dúvida quanto ao redimensionamento de imagem em CSS.

Tenho uma imagem 1920x1080.

Essa imagem deve ser redimensionada automaticamente para que caiba em qualquer tela, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Vejam este site: http://www.dadaabstories.org/

Na parte de cima começa a passar um vídeo, é assim que eu quero que fique minha página, mas no lugar do vídeo, uma imagem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a propriedade background-size: cover para redimensionar a imagem de fundo.
Por exemplo:

```
body{
   background-image: url('beach.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: O problema é que não é uma imagem de fundo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente aplicar:

```
background: url(sua-imagem.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```